# Best method for checking the length of a 'chain'

Tags: jquery, optimization

I'm coding a small web app, in which a user will have a row of n elements, and he's required to toggle each element to true/false, according to his own criteria.

Each time the user toggles an element, I have to check the length of the 'chain' of true elements the toggled element might be part of. examples:

```
0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 ? //if user selects '1', the chain length is 4
0 ? 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 //if user selects '1', the chain length is 3
0 0 1 1 1 ? 1 1 0 0 //if user selects '1', the chain length is 6
```

I'm thinking about the best way of doing this.

All elements will have representation both in a JSON object and as DOM objects (for example `<div>`s).

**one option** is to simply run through the entire array with every click. This is ok, as the maximum amount of elements will be about 1000. But it doesn't seem to be the most efficient way.

**another option** is to take the clicked element and step backwards while counting each additional true element, until reaching a false element. then doing the same from the clicked element onwards. This seems better to me but maybe it's an unnecessary hassle.

I need help deciding which method is most suitable for this problem. Factors are (not surprisingly) -

1. Performance - it mustn't cause any lags on the client-side - the chain length must be determined instantly.
2. Maintainability.

**I realise this question might seem a bit subjective, and maybe it is, but I figured this must be a familiar problem with a familiar solution that I'm not aware of.**

I'll be using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

I would find the longest chain first. This will require iterating through your elements once.

After that, radiate outwards from the position of each changed element and find the longest chain.

```
$('.box').click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');

    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('active');

    var $next = $this.nextUntil(':not(.active)');
    var $prev = $this.prevUntil(':not(.active)');

    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {
        var $chain = $next.add($prev).add($this);
    } else {
        var $chain = $next.length > $prev.length ? $next : $prev;
    }

    $chain.addClass('selected');
});
```

If that chain is longer than the longest chain, you found your new longest chain.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EDVvN/4/**

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution that seems to be "efficient enough" in that there was no lag in the browser during my testing.  I will say that 1000 elements is not a lot relative to what the browser should be able to handle, but it is a *lot* for a user (I could only test clicking about 100 elements before I started to feel physical pain).

This works with a simple array of integers and doesn't touch much of the DOM except for the individual input elements when they are clicked.  I assume that operations on integer arrays are about as fast as you can get for sorting and aggregating.

```
//record an array of selected indices
var items = [];

//Delegation will speed things up (hopefully)
$("body").on('change', 'input', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var index = $this.index();

    //`items` should only ever contain clicked elements
    //We only have to worry about the one item with each click for now
    if ($this.prop('checked')) {
        items.push(index);
    }
    else {
        items.splice(items.indexOf(index), 1);
    }
    items.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
    var chains = [1];
    var chain = 0;
    try {
        //iterate over the items array.  This should be fast even for 100 items
        items.reduce(function (prev, next) {
            //items are out of order; record currently found chain
            if (next - 1 !== prev) {
                chain++;
                chains.push(1);
            }
            else {
                chains[chain]++;
            }
            return next;
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        //handle TypeError thrown by `.reduce` on empty array
        //this also accounts for the "0" case (no elements selected)
        chains = [0];
    }
    //Get the longest found chain
    console.log(Math.max.apply(undefined, chains));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/svUrs/2/

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to step backwards and then forwards from the clicked element until reaching a zero sounds efficient and not especially complex. However, one might consider it premature optimization-- checking 1000 elements will not likely impact browser responsiveness (this is easy enough for you to test), so if you think the less-efficient algorithm is faster to code and/or easier to maintain it is arguably the best solution.